# Question regarding matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to get my head around a statistical topic where I look at dental measurements on eleven girls and sixteen boys at four different ages. One matrix that shows up is the following one:

\begin{matrix} 
I_{11}^T&0_{16}^T\\
0_{11}^T&I_{16}^T\\
\end{matrix}

Can someone perhaps explain to me what this expression means?

Comment: As a guess I would assume that I means the identity matrix (ones on the main diagonal and zero elsewhere). The subscript implies it’s dimensions. 0 is a matrix of zeros. Not clear to me why not just write I_27 and why there’s transpose but without a link to the paper it’s hard to understand clearly.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22block+matrix%22.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that these are row vectors and the subscripts indicate their length.  for example, $I_{11}$ represents a row vector of 11 ones and $0_{16}$ represents a row vector of 16 zeros.  Taking into account the transposes then the whole matrix $X$ is (11+16) x 2 and if

- $y$ is a vector of the 11+16 observations of the 11 girls followed by the 16 boys
- $\beta$ is the length 2 vector of regression coefficients
- $\epsilon$ is the vector of residuals

then we have the regression:

$y = X\beta + \epsilon$

We have assumed that the regression is on sex and does not involve ages.

### R Code

In R here are three ways to compute $X$:

1. following question as closely as possible:

```
I11 <- matrix(1, 1, 11); O11 <- matrix(0, 1, 11)
I16 <- matrix(1, 1, 16); O16 <- matrix(0, 1, 16)
X <- cbind(rbind(t(I11), t(O16)), rbind(t(O11), t(I16)))
```

2. directly using matrix:

```
matrix(rep(diag(2), c(11, 16, 11, 16)), ncol = 2)
```

3. extracting from regression:

```
# y <- ...whatever...
levs <- c("girl", "boy")
x <- factor(rep(levs, c(11, 16)), levs)
fm <- lm(y ~ x + 0)
X <- model.matrix(fm)
```

Comment: Than you very much, will take a look att what you've written.